# Spawning of App Cloud tag

Tags: discussion

I would like to suggest that we create synonyms between App Cloud and Salesforce1 Platform tags.

App Cloud is essentially a rebranding of SF1 Platform (the joint platform offerings of Salesforce), primarily focusing on Heroku *and* Force.com (until something else joins in.

I know the purpose of SFSE is not to be the branding rubber stamp of Salesforce, but App Cloud is bound to begin cropping up.

What do people think?

Comment: In the 1980's & 1990's people were "finding themselves", then people and companies were "reinventing themselves", now companies and people are "rebranding". Perhaps we should say that Salesforce is doing "dreamspeak"?

Answer (score 5):

ROTFL at "branding rubber stamp of Salesforce". That's a good one Peter!

I've no issues with creating the AppCloud tag for those who might use it. For the present time, I think people are *really* going to be confused if you redirect Salesforce1 tags to point to AppCloud, which is what creating a synonym does!

There's enough confusion as it is between Force.com Platform, Salesforce Platform, Salesforce CRM, Force.com, Salesforce1, Salesforce1 Mobile, and all the other terminology that's floating around out there. Users are still having trouble grasping that everything that *was* Salesforce is now Salesforce1 even though initially people associate the latter only with the mobile app. Not to mention that NOW we have Lightning! Need I say more?